# Facebook Activity Feed functionality for my own FB app

Tags: facebook, android-activity, feed

Is there a way to post an activity feed on your profile? For ex, on the image below, I want to know if I can do a similar post but created using my own app

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQu9K.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way for an Application to manually generate a story similar to this. The closest you could do is [post a message to their wall](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#feed).